# How does the following code to work? How to work with struct_time objects?

Tags: python

If I do the following I can convert from a `time_struct` object to a `datetime` object:

```
mydate = datetime.datetime(*time.localtime()[:6])
```

How does this code work? What do the `*` and the `[:6]` mean?

Comment: Here's the link to the Python reference: http://docs.python.org/reference/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), `[:6]` is [slicing](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range). That is whatever is returned from `time.localtime()` (i.e., `time.struct_time`) is sliced and first 6 elements are unpacked and 6 arguments passed to `datetime.datetime`.

There are plenty of question on SO re all of these topics.

Answer (score 3):

`*time.localtime()` means, that the `tuple` returned from localtime is unpacked (turned into arguments passed to datetime). `[:6]` means that only a slice of the `tuple` is used, this operator returns new `tuple` of first six elements.

This code takes `localtime` from the time module in the form of a tuple and passes it into nice `datetime` object constructor. It's good to work on datetime objects, they are much nicer then `localtime` tuples. `localtime` returns a `tuple` with values representing local time.

Comment: Reference 1: The "*" operator: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Comment: Reference 2: The [:] slicing operation: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#slicings